# Understanding this complex declaration

Tags: c++

```
static void (* __set_malloc_handler(void (*__f)()))();
```

I think `__set_malloc_handler` is a function pointer, and it points to a function which also needs a function pointer. But, I have no idea how to understand the whole statement. How does it work?

Comment: `__set_malloc_handler` is a function, not a function pointer. It's argument and return values are function pointers.

Comment: [Clockwise\Spiral Rule.](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: Alternatively, you can read this page on the [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html).

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=static+void+%28*+__set_malloc_handler%28void+%28*%29%28%29%29%29%28%29%3B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to understand with some aliasing.

```
//pointer to function taking no arguments and void return
typedef void(*function_pointer)();

//function taking "function_pointer" and returning "function_pointer"
function_pointer __set_malloc_handler(function_pointer __f);
```

---

To read something like that, I recommend the [right-left rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). It's what I always use. There's also a [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), but I get annoyed when it doesn't form a perfect spiral and I get too distracted by that to focus. You probably won't have that issue.

The explanation on either page is more thorough, but here's a crash course.

Essentially, read these symbols as:

1. `*` = "pointer to"
2. `(...)` = "function taking `...`"
3. `[...]` = "array of size `...`"

Read to the right until you find a `)` that didn't have a matching `(` yet. Then read to the left until you find a `(` to match it. Start reading right again. If you hit the end of the line on the right, you finish reading to the left.

To the immediate right of the identifier `__set_malloc_handler` is an open parenthetical `(`, meaning it is a function. Everything from that to the matching `)` is the parameter type. I'd recommend ignoring it at first and coming back to it later. Step by step:

```
       __set_malloc_handler(...)    //function taking ...
     (*__set_malloc_handler(...))   //and returning a pointer
     (*__set_malloc_handler(...))() //to a function taking no arguments
void (*__set_malloc_handler(...))() //that returns void
```

Looking at the parameter, we have:

```
     (*__f)   //pointer
     (*__f)() //to function taking no arguments
void (*__f)() //and returning void
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I love the right-left rule, and I learned much from it. You gave me a fish, and taught me how to fish. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

`__set_malloc_handler` is a function that takes a "function pointer to a void function" and returns a "function pointer to a void function". Keyword `static` makes it only visible to the current file.